# ASP.NET calling methods from another project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, rest, asp.net-ajax

I am developing a system comsisting of two ASP.NET projects. The first project is only accessible from a local IP and holds all the methods and has access to the database. The second project only consists of a userinterface and should get the needed data, by calling methods in the first project, which returns the needed data. The second project, is available from any IP.

My question is, how can I connect these two projects, so that the second project can access methods in an object, in the first project, using ASP.NET?

I have tried with JQuery and AJAX, but with those, I can only access static methods.

Comment: You will need to create a WCF service, WEB API or standard web service to be able to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Generic Handler" (a .ashx file). 
With this you can expose a HTTP endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your first project to a [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) Project which has endpoints exposed to clients to do different things over HTTP protocol. You will call these end points from your second project.

Your first project will act like a web service which does all the business logic and database things. Your second project will be thin UI client, which will communicate to the first as needed for getting data,updating data etc.

You can use [`HttpWebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class in your first project to communicate to the end points of your Web API project.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the first project has a userinterface as well, which is only accessesble from a local IP. Is this still possible, if the project is a Web API?

Comment: It is possible, Your first project can have MVC controller view for your user interface along with your Web api controllers for your REST endpoints.